# Нужны ли запятые в оборотах со словом "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Скоро будет 15 лет() как я возглавляю компанию.
2. Как практикующий врач()я стараюсь уделять достаточно внимания каждому пациенту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Скоро будет 15 лет, как я возглавляю компанию. **Здесь запятая ставится,** это  СПП. Но **запятая не ставится при инверсии**: Я скоро 15 лет как возглавляю компанию.

Другие примеры: Я скоро пять лет как живу в Москве. Занятия вот уже месяц как начались. Тебе есть в мире что забыть.

2) Как практикующий врач, я стараюсь уделять достаточно внимания каждому пациенту. **Оборот со значением причины обособляется.**

**Для сравнения:** Я интересуюсь этой проблемой (именно) как практикующий врач. **Оборот со значением "в качестве" не обособляется.** Здесь по смыслу должно подразумеваться какое-либо противопоставление, например как практикующий врач и как научный работник. Паузы нет, логическое ударение делается на обороте.

Comment: Сергей, а почему вы поставили запятую во втором примере с инверсией?

Comment: По невнимательности, конечно, запятая не нужна. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Запятые нужны. В первом предложение союз "как" вводит придаточное предложение, во втором оборот **с как** имеет причинное значение: **будучи практикующим врачом.** ...

Answer (score 1):

~1. Здесь придется ставить, хотя по смыслу здесь всего лишь время, обстоятельство. Грамматически тут ССП, "как я стал" - придаточное.

Дкмаю, что так правильно, несмотря на единичные примеры обратного в Нацкопусе.

~2. От смысла зависит. Я бы здесь скорее увидел обстоятельство образа действия при сказуемом и запятую не ставил. Но боюсь, что меня не поймут те, кто увидит здесь причину.

Не поленился и это посмотреть в Нацкорпусе - полный разнобой. Но это объективная ситуация, пунктуация тут ориентируется на субъективное восприятие оборота "как практикующий врач", а это может быть и ***обстоятельством образа действия*** и сравнительным оборотом с приравниванием "как [будто бы] практикующий врач" (здесь маловероятно), и, что самое плохое, ***значение причины***. Реально может знать только автор.